# How do I write a code to copy, paste, top down in intervals of 15-16 using the next line within my worksheet?

Tags: copy, intervals, paste, worksheet

I am trying to convert an incoming file to complete repetitive tasks. 1. Insert 15 blank rows. (completed) 2. Copy first row, columns A:D into the blank rows below. 3. Process two needs to continue this process for all 500+ clients. 4. Column E begins with the first date for that time period, and it needs to break the dates up in the blank cells below. (11/16/19, 11/17/19, and so on, but only for the empty blank rows in the column. Almost everything I have found has been to another sheet, but all this needs to happen in the active working sheet. Can anyone help me, please?

I have a code for inserting the blank rows. However, everything I have tried to copy either overwrites my other data or stops after the first client. I am not sure if I should add on to the existing code or create separate code for the other two tasks. The other blank cells have to be keyed in manually, and this would create a lot of time to focus on completing the manual fields.

Sub InsertRowsAtIntervals()

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xInterval As Integer
Dim xRows As Integer
Dim xRowsCount As Integer
Dim xNum1 As Integer

Dim xNum2 As Integer

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xWs As Worksheet
xTitleId = "Inquiry Box"

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
xRowsCount = WorkRng.Rows.count
xInterval = Application.InputBox("Enter row interval. ", xTitleId, 1, Type:=1)
xRows = Application.InputBox("How many rows to insert at each interval? ", xTitleId, 1, Type:=1)
xNum1 = WorkRng.Row + xInterval
xNum2 = xRows + xInterval

Set xWs = WorkRng.Parent
For i = 1 To Int(xRowsCount / xInterval)
    xWs.Range(xWs.Cells(xNum1, WorkRng.Column), xWs.Cells(xNum1 + xRows - 1, WorkRng.Column)).Select
    Application.Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    xNum1 = xNum1 + xNum2
```

Next
End Sub

It would be nice to run a macro on the monthly incoming file and run a macro that handles all these small steps. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a picture of what I am trying to do will help.

Comment: Good news! It turns out I did not need a code for the second half. I used the Go To Special and created a macro around my parameters. Thank you to all those who shared, I do not believe I could have completed this on my own. Thank you StackOverFlow for this platform that allowed me to reach out to the community! Together, we got it done! I look forward to coming back and seeing if I can assist someone else with their project. Best wishes ~I – I